# WooCommerce Plugin - Displaying Price other than Minimum on Products

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have an eCommerce site that has fabric for sale. When setting up product variations, I know the default is to show the minimum price in the string. I don't want to display the minimum price, instead, I need the price to be picked up from the fourth line/price in my variation string. For example, if I have a product that is $20 per yard, I want the product post to read "Price per Yard: $20" rather than "From: $5" as customers can purchase products in increments of 1/4 yard, 1/2 yard, 3/4 yard, 1 yard, etc. I also want to change the text from "from" to "price per yard" for my variations. Please point me in the right direction to make this change in WooCommerce. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

look at woocommerce.css and find the section for the price.

you can right click the item in chrome and inspect element to determine where the price comes from, post that section of code here and I'll help you out.